# bindkey vi-cmd-mode causes other bindings to be unrecognized after exiting command mode

Tags: zsh, vi, key-bindings

I am in zsh, and have used `bindkey -v` to use vi key mappings in zsh. I often use `<C-W>` to delete the previous word, but when I type `<esc>` go into normal mode/vi-cmd-mode, then go back into insert mode with `i` or `a`, I can no longer use bindings like `<C-W>` until I run a new command. Is there anyway I can still use bindings like  from bindkey after going into normal mode then back into insert mode? Thanks!

This is the output of `bindkey`:

```
"^A"-"^C" self-insert
"^D" list-choices
"^E" "^[a ^[dbxxa"
"^F" self-insert
"^G" list-expand
"^H" vi-backward-delete-char
"^I" expand-or-complete
"^J" accept-line
"^K" self-insert
"^L" clear-screen
"^M" accept-line
"^N"-"^P" self-insert
"^Q" vi-quoted-insert
"^R" redisplay
"^S"-"^T" self-insert
"^U" vi-kill-line
"^V" vi-quoted-insert
"^W" vi-backward-kill-word
"^X"-"^Z" self-insert
"^[" vi-cmd-mode
"^[OA" up-line-or-search
"^[OB" down-line-or-search
"^[OC" vi-forward-char
"^[OD" vi-backward-char
"^[[A" up-line-or-history
"^[[B" down-line-or-history
"^[[C" vi-forward-char
"^[[D" vi-backward-char
"^\\\\"-"~" self-insert
"^?" vi-backward-delete-char
"\M-^@"-"\M-^?" self-insert
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The widget `vi-backward-kill-word` (which is by default bound to <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> in *vi-ins* mode) only deletes back up to the point where you last entered insert mode. So it only seems to be not working when you do not actually enter more text.

An easy workaround for that is to use the widget `backward-kill-word` instead. You can just remap the key binding for <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> (this needs to be done after `bindkey -v`):

```
bindkey -v
bindkey '^W' backward-kill-word
```